# Spring MVC subscribe to failed startup of Servlet WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an application that uses tomcat and custom Spring initialisation mechanism (not Spring Boot).
I'm trying to add here Spring Web MVC. According documentation there are two contexts `Root WebApplicationContext` that is populated via `ContextLoaderListener` and `Servlet WebApplicationContext` that is isolated from the Root context.
[image]

All works good.
Bu we have a health-check mechanism in the root context that is listening ContextRefreshedEvent event, filtering Lifecycle beans and checking them by calling isRunning method.

The problem is happening when `Servlet WebApplicationContext` can not start for instance because of `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and `ContextRefreshedEvent` is not published, so the root context does not even know that the application is not alive.

Is there a way that I can collect information about all the contexts in the app and check if all of them are running?